# Configuration Page for Package

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, package, configuration

Im new to Salesforce Package.
After I create a package, usually we need to put some configurations for the package.

Where is the usual place to put this links(I created one visualforce page for my package configuration).

How would I set it up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Go to Setup > Customize > Home > **Custom Links**

   [image: Customize Home Custom Links]
2. Create a new custom link to your VF page (eg /apex/ns__pageName)

   [image: Custom Links]
3. Edit your **package** and specify the custom link

   [image]
4. Now a **[Configure]** button will appear after install. Guide your users to click it.

   [image: Configure Package]

Comment: If you don't mind, I wanna ask another question. How do I set the permission whom can configure the package? Is that the organisation who installed the package responsibility?

Comment: yes @ben only System Administrators can view the package configuration page by default

Comment: I believe this has been replaced by the "Post Install Instructions" option, selecting a Visualforce "Post Install Page".

Comment: Custom Links aren't available Lightning UI. We need to switch to the Classic UI to create those.